# Is it bad to run script and DOMs before html tag

Tags: javascript

Is it bad to run script and DOMs before html tag? I have a floating window script on my page created with divs and table, will it harm search engine crawling site? Is this bad coding?

Comment: Yes, it's bad coding

Comment: Before `<html>` is kinda weird but inside `<head>` is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only is it bad, it's invalid code and invalid code can have a detrimental effect on search engine optimization.

Always validate your code, which you can do at **http://validator.w3.org**.

The `<script>` element is allowed anywhere inside the `<head>` and/or `<body>` elements and where you place it can have serious effects on how your code runs or if it runs at all.

Browsers read the contents of a web page from left to right, top to bottom. If a `script` includes a reference to an element that hasn't been read by the browser yet, the script will fail. You can be sure that the browser has read all the relevant HTML by the time your script executes by placing the `<script>` element just prior to the closing `body` tag (`</body>`) or you can place your script prior to the element(s) it references, but you'll have to wrap your code inside of an event handling function that doesn't trigger until after the element(s) have been parsed into memory.

Often times, the code in one `script` element will depend on code from another `script` element. In those cases, it is essential that the scripts be included in your document in the proper sequence. A very good example of this is the use of the popular JQuery JavaScript library. You must have the `script` that references JQuery located prior to any other scripts that intend to use the library.

Additionally, when the browser encounters a `script` element (that doesn't have the `async` or `defer` attributes placed on it), it begins executing the script's contents synchronously, which means that nothing else can happen with your page while the script is running. This can lead to the user interface being "blocked" (frozen). This is another reason that scripts are often placed at the end of the `body`, because at least the main contents of the page will have been parsed and visible to the user at this time and they are not often even aware of the blocking taking place.

Comment: Thanks you so much, now I have evidence to prove I was right.